# how to insert a delay between pipelining commands in a bash : ohai block_device | jq -r keys[1] | (printf /dev/ && cat)

Tags: unix, chef-infra

Here ohai is a chef cli, during the execution i am getting the output values as just /dev/ , but expected value here is /dev/xvdh.

How to reconstruct this command to get fast response.

how to insert a delay between pipelining commands in a bash : ohai block_device | jq -r keys[1] | (printf /dev/ && cat) > /tmp/output.txt

Comment: Why not just do it in Ruby code?

Comment: I tried using shellout ruby block, but i am not able to assign the command out to a node attribute.

ruby_block 'block_device' do
    block do
        Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)
        command = 'ohai block_device | jq -r keys[1] | (printf /dev/ && cat)'
        command_out = shell_out(command)
        node.run_state['new_device'] = command_out.stdout
    end
    action :create
end

Comment: Ohai data is already loaded as node attributes in Chef, you don't need to run it again.

Comment: I want to really take the EBS device name separately and then mount it.Since AWS EC2 device name changes for some instance type, i have to get the ohai block device and taking the last volume using jquery keys[1] and then trying to get the value /dev/xvdh.. but somehow when i run the execute resource i am getting only /dev in the output. this happens only first time when server getting provisioned , if i bootstrap second time it works like a charm..i am thinking of two options..i have to rewrite the command to get faster response or i am thinking to sleep the execute resource for few more sec

Comment: execute 'ohai_blockdevice' do
  command "ohai block_device > /tmp/ohai_id.out"
  not_if { ::File.exist?('/tmp/ohai.out') }
end.run_action(:run)

execute 'device_create' do
  command  `echo "/dev/$(cat /tmp/ohai_id.out | jq -r keys[1])" > /tmp/device.out`
  not_if { ::File.exist?('/tmp/block_device.out') }
end.run_action(:run)

if File.exist?('/tmp/device.out')
  device_name = ::File.read('/tmp/device.out').chomp
  execute 'create_mkfs' do
    command "mkfs.ext4 #{device_name}"
    not_if "grep #{device_name} /proc/mounts"
  end
end

Comment: Rewind, are you trying to do this inside Chef or in some other script?

Comment: Also comments don't allow formatting so don't paste code in them.

Comment: I am trying to do this inside chef

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so from inside Chef you don't need to do any of this, just use the existing Ohai data in the node attributes:

```
node['block_device'].keys.each do |dev_name|
  dev_path = "/dev/#{dev_name}"
  # execute resources here
end
```

Comment: wow thats great, can i get the keys[1] only by any chance here ? in my case i will have only two volume, first one is root.. i am least worried about. 2nd one is EBS volume which is in keys[1] inside block device

Comment: `dev_name = node['block_device'].keys.first`, but remember we don't promise a specific order in there so you shouldn't do that.